# Difference between <% %> and <%= %> in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What the difference between

```
<% some code %>
```

and

```
<%= some code %>
```

in RoR?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Think of it like this:

```
<% execute this code and display nothing %>
```

and

```
<%= execute this code and display the result in the view %>
```

So, for example you could do this:

```
<% @values = ['eenie', 'menie', 'miney', 'mo' ] %>
<% @values.each do |value| %>
  The current value is <%= value %>!
<% end %>
```

Comment: <% =  %> This is the ruby syntax you can use this for view and  this <%  %>  you use for condition, loop or debugger.

Comment: <% %> this tag to not echo the code output whereas <%= %> this echo the output of the code segment

Answer (score 0):

`<%= some code %>` will evaluate the statement and display it in the view.
`<% some code %>` will only evaluate the statement.