# The difference between <%=, <% and <%- in ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

As I wrote in the title. In Ejs what's the difference between `<%=`, `<%` and `<%-`? for example I saw this code `<% include ../partials/header.ejs %>`, and then there is this code `<%= title %>`. I also saw `<%-` somewhere but cannot find a code example anywhere. So what's the difference? When do I use which?

I found this but it's for `ruby on rails` [Difference between <% %> and <%= %> in RoR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125894/difference-between-and-in-ror)

Comment: https://github.com/tj/ejs#features look at what research can do buddy (this isn't an answer i'm just certain you didn't look hard enough :D)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10330401/7739188

Comment: I tried googling `ejs <%` but I guess google doesn't like special chars. Will do better job searching next time. Sorry!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following is from [ejs docs](http://ejs.co/) (tag section):

> - <% 'Scriptlet' tag, for control-flow, no output
> - <%= Outputs the value into the template (HTML escaped)
> - <%- Outputs the unescaped value into the template

See the difference between escaped and unescaped html [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727910/what-is-escaped-unescaped-output)

Comment: What is unescaped value?

Comment: Not sure what unescaped value means but `<%-` is for including other code, and this is the syntax for doing so: `<%- include('<path>', <object with extra parameters>) %>`, e.g., `<%- include('../includes/end.ejs') %>` for the footer.

Comment: Unescaped value could mean non-commented code, `<%-`  filters out the commented portion while `<%=` includes commented code and prints value as is.