Using stored WYSIWYG html data (shows as plain text)
I have a WYSIWYG editor on my ejs site to my modify a blog article. It works great, it does what it’s suppose to do, it generates the html as it should, it stores the generated html into my database.
When I try and retrieve the entry, it shows as plain text. If I manually add the generated html it works.
<div id="innerdiv"></div>
<script>
    const doesntWork = "<%=post%>";
    const works = "<p>MODIFIED POST NO ENCODING</p><p data-f-id='pbf' style='text-align: center; font-size: 14px; margin-top: 30px; opacity: 0.65; font-family: sans-serif;'>Powered by <a href='https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor?pb=1' title='Froala Editor'>Froala Editor</a></p>"

    document.getElementById("innerdiv").
        innerHTML += doesntWork;
</script>

Outcome : works => https://gyazo.com/948d4aba1a5efdfec64dcc940728fdaf
Outcome : doesntWork => https://gyazo.com/5d75c2777831a1a763d3b798dfce59c2
<%=post%> : https://i.gyazo.com/604ed6598fe89bb960d4ca404135527b.png
Page Render : https://i.sstatic.net/mRtCAvDs.png
Am I missing a step?

Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.

I see "<%=post%>" which looks like some form of template language or framework, which likely escapes the HTML for you. You need to provide information on what you use to render your page.

Likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/48522961/2232127 though I'm not sure if EJS is used here

Do also note that if you allow users to directly modify HTML on your page you open yourself up to XSS attacks

The images aren’t errors. There are no errors.

After 15 hours this article lead me to the answer sorry for pre-mature posting I guess.  Render a variable as HTML in EJS
The answer is that you wanna use unescaped raw output, the html will then render.
Unescaped raw output with <%- %>
